# Logback stops logging while running

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

We are using logback-1.2.3 with SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE, and we package the web application to war-file which can running in Tomcat(Tomcat is running about 30 war-files). Each application in Tomcat produces an individual logfile. Logging is correctly running when the application startup, but it randomly stops after a period of time(random period and random logfile). Our logback configuration is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="/var/logs/services" />
    <springProperty scope="context" name="log.name" source="spring.application.name" defaultValue="localhost.log"/>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/${log.name}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder"  level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor"  level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.QueryParameters" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan" level="INFO" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I've checked the following things:

```
1. lsof -p <tomcat pid>
    I can not find the file descriptor of the corresponding log filename, which means that logfile has already been closed by Tomcat(Why?);
2. check the Tomcat console logfile(catalina.out)
    I found the following Exception, but don't known whether it makes sense;

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
            at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.warn(Logger.java:692)
            at com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger$WarnLogger.log(Slf4jMLog.java:223)
            at com.mchange.v2.log.slf4j.Slf4jMLog$Slf4jMLogger.log(Slf4jMLog.java:256)
            at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:749)
```

Tomcat version is 8.5.32.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Or, we mis-configured the logback?

Comment: Did you include logback-classic in your project (if maven, include pom)

Comment: Please check if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477145/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-ch-qos-logback-classic-spi-throwableproxy

Comment: @Antoniossss I've included logback-classic-1.2.3.jar in our project

Comment: @Jayaraj Tks, I've read that thread before I submit the question here, but it does not help...